# Подсчет количества символов в строке

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Почему в "Edit2" неверное количество символов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if(!error)
    {
            char s_russian[] =
            {
                    "àáâãäå¸æçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"
            };
            char s_latin[] =
            {
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            };
            char S_RUSSIAN[] =
            {
                    "ÀÁÂÃÄÅ¨ÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞß"
            };
            char S_LATIN[] =
            {
                    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            };
            char s_num[] =
            {
                    "0123456789"
            };
            char s_esc[] =
            {
                    "`~@#¹$;%^:&?*()-_=+|[{]}<>"
            };


            char password_chars[] = "";


            if(CheckBox1->Checked == true && CheckBox3->Checked == true)
            {
                   strcat(password_chars, s_russian);
            }
            if(CheckBox2->Checked == true && CheckBox3->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_latin);
            }
            if(CheckBox1->Checked == true && CheckBox4->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, S_RUSSIAN);
            }
            if(CheckBox2->Checked == true && CheckBox4->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, S_LATIN);
            }
            if(CheckBox5->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_num);
            }
            if(CheckBox6->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_esc);
            }

            int password_chars_length = strlen(password_chars);
               Edit2->Text = password_chars_length;
    }
```

Comment: У вас русские буквы в какой кодировке ? В UTF8 например русские буквы занимают 2 байта. А 'Й' может быть как 2 так и 4 байта

Comment: @Mike А как мне тогда длину строки подсчитать не парясь с байтами?

Comment: А "не парясь" не получится. Вы же потом небось еще захотите из этой строки какие нибудь симолы получать для пароля и вам надо будет учитывать их длину, во первых что бы брать по 2 байта когда положено и во вторых что бы не попасть случайно на середину символа. Так что проще было бы использовать какие нибудь строки из C++, а не тип char

Comment: @Mike дело в том что если я выбираю один параметр, цифры, символы, все считает верно, но если несколько то уже не верно.

Comment: @Mike Например, русский,  алфавит в верхнем и нижнем регистре считает верно. С латинским так же. Латинский + русский в нижнем регистре выводит верно, вот если к этому прибавить в верхнем регистре уже не верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char password_chars[] = "";
/* ... */
strcat(password_chars, S_RUSSIAN);
```

Как ЭТО у вас вообще работает? Программа должна падать со страшным грохотом на первом же `strcat()`.

Либо выделяйте под `password_chars[]` сразу столько места, сколько займут все наборы символов:

```
char password_chars[sizeof(s_russian)+sizeof(s_latin)...];
```

Либо воспользуйтесь `std::string`, как вам и предлагали изначально.

Comment: C strcat всё нормально, и выводит все символы без проблем. Мне нужно знать выбранный размер символов так как мне создавать рандом для подбора пароля.

Comment: *C strcat всё нормально* -- нет, не нормально. То, что оно у вас работает - это просто случайность.

Comment: Хорошо, главное работает :)

Comment: @Евгений У вас в программе неопределенное поведение. вы копируете строку в не зарезервированную область памяти. 20 раз будет все ок, а на 21 раз оно сделает что нибудь неожиданное, например винт отформатирует

Comment: @Mike Ага, удалит интернет.

Comment: @Евгений А зря не верите, стек порушите, первый же выход из функции на разрущенном стеке приведет к переходу на случайный участок кода, приложение конечно скорее всего просто аварийно завершится, но есть вероятность выполнения чего нибудь осмысленного

Comment: @Mike Смотрите мой ответ.

Comment: @Евгений Ну вот видите, значит этот ответ совершенно верный (стоит его принять). Проблема в разрушении стека. А как она выразится никогда не известно, на то оно и неопределенное поведение https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @mike А при объявлении password_chars[] мне нужно еще +1 учитывать 0 символ?

Comment: @Евгений Конечно. лучше всегда с запасом делать, что бы не парится. 1 Кб оперативной памяти не много

Comment: @mike Подскажите, как объявить char string [n] от int n?

Comment: @mike Получается только если написать число

Comment: @Евгений, да не нужен тут массив, используйте `std::string` и не забивайте себе голову всякой ненужной ерундой. Заодно и надёжность кода повысится. Но если так хочется именно массив в C-стиле - как правильно вычислить и задать его размер я уже написал в ответе (как сумму `sizeof()` всех вспомогательных массивов).